# R - Create a column with entries only for the first row of each subset

Tags: r

For instance if I have this data:

```
ID  Value   
1   2
1   2
1   3
1   4
1   10
2   9
2   9
2   12
2   13
```

And my goal is to find the smallest value for each ID subset, and I want the number to be in the first row of the ID group while leaving the other rows blank, such that:

```
ID  Value   Start
1   2       2
1   2       
1   3       
1   4       
1   10      
2   9       9
2   9       
2   12      
2   13
```

My first instinct is to create an index for the IDs using

```
A <- transform(A, INDEX=ave(ID, ID, FUN=seq_along)) ## A being the name of my data
```

Since I am a noob, I get stuck at this point. For each ID=n, I want to find the min(A$Value) for that ID subset and place that into the cell matching condition of ID=n and INDEX=1.

Any help is much appreciated! I am sorry that I keep asking questions :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
within(A, INDEX <- "is.na<-"(ave(Value, ID, FUN = min), c(FALSE, !diff(ID))))

  ID Value INDEX
1  1     2     2
2  1     2    NA
3  1     3    NA
4  1     4    NA
5  1    10    NA
6  2     9     9
7  2     9    NA
8  2    12    NA
9  2    13    NA
```

**Update:**

*How it works?* The command `ave(Value, ID, FUN = min)` applies the function `min` to each subset of `Value` along the values of `ID`. For the example, it returns a vector of five times `2` and four times `9`. Since all values except the first in each subset should be `NA`, the function `"is.na<-"` replaces all values at the logical index defined by `c(FALSE, !diff(ID))`. This index is `TRUE` if a value is identical with the preceding one.

Comment: Can you add a little bit of explanation for this one? It's doing my head in.

Comment: @Sven Hohenstein: This solution works even better! My "Value" is actually "Date" in the format %m/%d/%Y (I didn't want to rely completely on others). The other solution does not apply well to Dates--it chooses the wrong minimum and maximum on some dates. I thought it is because R didn't recognize my data as dates, but after using as.Date() errors ensue. Then I tried your method and all the dates are correct.Thanks!

Comment: @sebastian-c I added an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. We just need to make a custom function instead of `seq_along` and to split `value` by `ID` (not `ID` by `ID`).

```
first_min <- function(x){
  nas <- rep(NA, length(x))
  nas[which.min(x)] <- min(x, na.rm=TRUE)
  nas
}
```

This function makes a vector of NAs and replaces the first element with the minimum value of `Value`.

```
transform(dat, INDEX=ave(Value, ID, FUN=first_min)) 

##   ID Value INDEX
## 1  1     2     2
## 2  1     2    NA
## 3  1     3    NA
## 4  1     4    NA
## 5  1    10    NA
## 6  2     9     9
## 7  2     9    NA
## 8  2    12    NA
## 9  2    13    NA
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, it is really helpful. I can't make it to work well for dates though

Comment: You could mitigate this by inserting a line after producing the vector of NAs in `first_min`: `if(inherits(x, "Date")) nas <- as.Date(nas)`

Comment: Do you mean inserting it into the end of the function?

Comment: @shirleywu Not at the end, between: `nas <- rep(NA, length(x))` and `nas[which.min(x)] <- min(x, na.rm=TRUE)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a tapply one-liner

```
df$Start<-as.vector(unlist(tapply(df$Value,df$ID,FUN = function(x){ return (c(min(x),rep("",length(x)-1)))})))
```

Comment: This also works well with Dates, and it leaves the empty cells empty!

Answer (score 0):

I keep going back to this question and the above answers helped me greatly. 
There is a basic solution for beginners too:

`A$Start<-NA
A[!duplicated(A$ID),]$Start<-A[!duplicated(A$ID),]$Value`

Thanks.